# Blinking page title

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm trying to get some notifications working for [AJAXChat](https://blueimp.net/ajax/). To do this all I want to do is get the title of the page to blink until focused.  To do this I'm using the [jquery-titlealert plugin](https://github.com/heyman/jquery-titlealert).  The problem is the html that is generated for the onload event is generated inside a js file shown here

```
return  '<div id="'
            + this.getMessageDocumentID(messageID)
            + '" class="'
            + rowClass
            + '">'
            + this.getDeletionLink(messageID, userID, userRole, channelID)
            + dateTime
            + '<span class="'
            + userClass
            + '"'
            + this.getChatListUserNameTitle(userID, userName, userRole, ip)
            + ' dir="'
            + this.baseDirection
            + '" onload="$.titleAlert('New Message');">'
            + userName
            + '</span>'
            + colon
            + this.replaceText(messageText)
            + '</div>';
    return
```

When I use this, it breaks the page.  If I replace `('New Message')` with `(New Message)` the page loads again but the notification isn't working.  I think this is because its displaying a Javascript function inside Javascript.  Anyone see anything here I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried escaping your quotes? I.e.:

```
+ '" onload="$.titleAlert(\'New Message\');">'
```

Any single quote (`'`) inside a single quoted string (or double quote (`"`) inside a double quoted string) needs a backslash (`\`) before it. See the [MDN String Literals documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#String_Literals) for more information about strings and proper character escaping.

Comment: The page doesn't break anymore but its still not working so that must not have been the problem.  I'll give you the answer answer anyway because you answered the question and were thorough with the explanation as to why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes.
Change this

```
'" onload="$.titleAlert('New Message');">'
```

to this

```
'" onload="$.titleAlert(\'New Message\');">'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the apostraphe's correctly:

```
+ '" onload="$.titleAlert(\'New Message\');">'
```